# mixture importance sampling

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, importance, numerical-integration

I have to integrate a 2 dimensional function between a range which has two peaks. I am trying to combine two Gaussian functions to get a distribution which is close to the function so as to use importance sampling to make a better estimate with lower variance. Do i have to draw from both the samples equally? My second question is how do i combine the samples drawn from both these distributions?

Answer (score 2):

If, when targeting the density $g(x)$ you use an importance density function of the form
$$\alpha f_1(x)+(1-\alpha) f_2(x)$$
which is called a mixture distribution you can either

1. simulate directly from the mixture, which amounts to simulate
   $$N_1\sim\mathcal{B}(n,\alpha)\quad x_1,\ldots,x_{N_1}\sim f_1\quad y_1,\ldots,y_{n-N_1}\sim f_2$$and use the importance weight$$\dfrac{g(x)}{\alpha f_1(x)+(1-\alpha) f_2(x)}$$for both the $x_i$'s and the $y_i$'s
2. set $1\le n_1\le n-1$ in an arbitrary manner and simulate
   $$x_1,\ldots,x_{n_1}\sim f_1\quad y_1,\ldots,y_{n-n_1}\sim f_2$$and use the importance weight$$\dfrac{n g(x)}{n_1 f_1(x)+(n-n_1) f_2(x)}$$for both the $x_i$'s and the $y_i$'s

since both approaches are correct. The second approach is described in Owen and Zhou (2000, JASA) and extended in our [adaptive multiple mixture paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.1254).

Comment: What if the we only know $f_1$ and $f_2$ up to a constant where these two constants are different?

Comment: If unbiasedness is not relevant, one can use bridge sampling to estimate the constants at no additional computational cost.

Comment: @Xian: Given the Bayes theorem, of the denominator, p(y), is intractable, so for a complicated model, estimate that constant p(y) is not straightforward and could be time consuming. Or maybe I do not understand you?

Comment: See e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.3887, https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.1214%2Fss%2F1028905934, https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/199589/Technical Report 568 Reweighting Monte Carlo Mixtures.pdf